# Grunt watch pattern.indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I'm trying to use Grunt's grunt-contrib-watch plugin to watch some files and then run the tasks, just what it was made for, this is my **Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        sass: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
            },
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'static/stylesheets/main.min.css': 'static/stylesheets/sass/main.scss',
                    /*'bower_components/foundation-sites/dist/foundation.min.css': 'bower_components/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss'*/
                }
            }
        },
        uglify: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'static/javascript/main.min.js': 'static/javascript/main.js'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            files: [
                '<%= sass.dist.files %>',
                '<%= uglify.dist.files %>'
            ],
            tasks: [
                'sass',
                'uglify'
            ]
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

When I run it, it runs over and over and over again, and when I stop it, I see I have  this message:

> Running "watch" task 
>   Waiting... 
>   Warning: pattern.indexOf is not a function

I really don't know what's the problem. Does anybody know what happens here?

**UPDATE:**

Apparently, the problem is because of the way I call the files, because I changed it to: 'static/stylesheets/sass/*.scss' and it worked well, but I would like to know why the other way doesn't work, because I think is a more useful way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

[grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) expects either a single pattern string or an array of pattern strings as the value of its `files` config. However, the templates you are using in your config evaluate to objects. Your `watch.files` value evaluates to the following:

```
files: [
    { 'static/stylesheets/main.min.css': 'static/stylesheets/sass/main.scss' },
    { 'static/javascript/main.min.js': 'static/javascript/main.js' }
]
```

When the pattern matching tries to run it fails because there is no `indexOf` method on an Object. Due to the fact that grunt-contrib-watch runs forever, there is an infinite loop of the trying and failing to build the list of watched files.

You would normally configure your watch files with something like the following:

```
files: [
    'static/**/*.scss',
    'static/**/*.js'
]
```

But the above will cause issues in your case because your minified JS file is in the same folder as your source JS file. You could probably get around this by adding `'!static/**/*.min.js'` to your files array, but a better solution would be to put all of your compiled files into a separate folder.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the values from the object:

```
watch: {
    files: [
        '<%= sass.dist.files.values() %>',
        '<%= uglify.dist.files.values() %>'
    ],
```

Comment: `values()` would need to go inside the `<%= %>`, e.g. `<%= sass.dist.files.values()` for it to work.

Comment: @applemonkey496 Thanks, fixed.